# Protecting a variable within a method | Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have a main method like this`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numofTrees = 3;
        intjumpingCapacity = 6;
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
        int b[] = {1,2,3,4};
        int c[] = {1,2,3,4};
        int d[] = {1,2,3,4};`
```

and a loop in main method

```
 while (treenum < numofTrees) {
                int tobeChecked = treenum;
                if (check(treenum, a, b,c,d) == true)
                    count++;


                treenum++;
            }
```

the check method is inside the same class, at the end of iteration the values are getting changed. I want to reinitialise to the original value at the start of each iteration. how can i do that. Do i need to put it in separate class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the arrays `a,b,c,d` in your while loop, so that they are re-initialized at the beginning of each iteration

```
  while (treenum < numofTrees) {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int c[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int d[] = {1,2,3,4};`
    int tobeChecked = treenum;
    if (check(treenum, a, b,c,d) == true)
      count++;
    treenum++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `check()` work with a *copy* of each array.

One way is to use [`Arrays.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) to pass a *copy* to the method:

```
if (check(treenum, Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length), Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length), Arrays.copyOf(c, c.length), Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length)))
```

or make copies within `check()`.

You can make the code more readable by creating a helper method:

```
private static int[] copy(int[] original) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);
}
```

then instead:

```
if (check(treenum, copy(a), copy(b), copy(c), copy(d)))
```

Note also the removal of the redundant `== true` from the `if` condition.